# Encountering java.net.SocketException: Connection reset while running sonar

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We are currently using sonar 4.3.3 release and hudson is used to have the E2E CI flow.It was observed in few of our build jobs that connection reset error was encountered but I am not sure what could be the probable reason.Below are the snippet of errors.Any inputs are highly appreciated.

***Snippet of Error 1 :***

```
:sonarRunner FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sonarRunner'.
> Fail to download libraries from server
* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':sonarRunner'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:289)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to download libraries from server
at org.sonar.runner.Bootstrapper.downloadBatchFiles(Bootstrapper.java:166)
at org.sonar.runner.Bootstrapper.createClassLoader(Bootstrapper.java:89)
at org.sonar.runner.Runner.createClassLoader(Runner.java:229)
at org.sonar.runner.Runner.execute(Runner.java:151)
at org.sonar.runner.Runner$execute.call(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.sonar.runner.SonarRunner.run(SonarRunner.groovy:52)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute
(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:212)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:201)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:533)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:516)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to download the file: http://XXXX/sonar/batch/xstream-1.3.1.jar
at org.sonar.runner.Bootstrapper.remoteContentToFile(Bootstrapper.java:115)
at org.sonar.runner.Bootstrapper.downloadBatchFiles(Bootstrapper.java:161)
... 56 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at org.sonar.runner.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:67)
at org.sonar.runner.Bootstrapper.remoteContentToFile(Bootstrapper.java:111)
... 57 more


BUILD FAILED
```

***Snippet of Error 2:***

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Unable to download '/batch_bootstrap/db?project=com.oracle.emaas.static.emcapms:develop' to: /scratch/aime/workspace/EMAAS-Prod-EMCAPMS_Build/.sonar/.sonartmp/preview1488173392228-0.h2.db
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.download(ServerClient.java:73)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.PreviewDatabase.downloadDatabase(PreviewDatabase.java:85)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.PreviewDatabase.start(PreviewDatabase.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:92)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:74)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.executeOldVersion(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.executeOldVersion(Unknown Source)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:245)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:110)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:72)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:60)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3066)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3060)
at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:192)
at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:120)
at com.google.common.io.Files.copy(Files.java:231)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.download(ServerClient.java:69)
... 31 more
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Performing Post build task...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using an unsupported version of SonarQube. 
You should migrate to latest LTS (5.6), as I don't expect anyone to be able to help you.